# grub does not boot when disk order changes

Tags: linux, grub2

My BIOS has some problems and sometimes boot order of disks changes. I thought that if I insall grub on to the MBR of second data disk, it may boot. First disk(sda) is for boot and operating system, second disk(sdb) is for /var. All partitions are labeled and fsck has labels as partition references.

I have install grub on to MBR of second disk by "grub-install /dev/sdb". It installed succesfully. However when I change the order to second disk to simulate, I got:
"Error 15: File not found" on grub stage.

```
   | root (hd0,0)                                                            |
   | kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.3 ro root=LABEL=/ console=ttyS0,19200n8        |
   | initrd /boot/initrd-3.5.3.img
```

If I change grub line "root (hd0,0)" to "root (hd1,0)" it boots correctly. However, this should work without admin intervention.

How can I build such a self working grub boot on case of a disk order change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have such a recent kernel, I suppose switching to grub2 should be an option. Then, grub2 can set the "root" based on the result of a search based of file systems uuids or files found in a filesystem. See the [GRUB2 search command documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#search) for details.